# SUM() column associated by ID from a separate table

Tags: mysql, sum

I have 2 tables, irc_users, contains the columns, id (int), nick (string[32]) amongst others. Then I have irc_pokemon, contains user_id (int), xp (int) again amongst others.

I'm looking to select nick from irc_users, then SUM() the xp column from irc_pokemon, associating them by the users id.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select u.nick, sum(xp) as xp_sum
from irc_users u
left outer join irc_pokemon p on p.user_id = u.id
group by u.nick
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT irc_users.nick , SUM(irc_pokemon.xp) FROM irc_users INNER JOIN irc_pokemon ON irc_pokemon.user_id = irc_users.id GROUP BY irc_users.nick
```

I assume irc_users.nick is unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
select nick,sum(xp) from irc_users,irc_pokemon where id=user_id group by id
```